# IO not found when using socket.io while building a chat application

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I was using socket.io and node.js for my application where I'm trying to use socket.io package and to import io package in my client.js I added the following script with my backend running at 3008 port as per documentation :

index.html:

```html
<script defer src="http://localhost:3008/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/client.js"></script>
```

client.js:

```js
const io2 = io.connect("http://localhost:3008");
```

but it kept showing the error that

> ReferenceError: io is not defined

after reading some documentation I added the following script to my html file.

```
<script defer src=""https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.esm.min.js""></script>
```

But the error persisted.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

While importing the script, you added `defer` and

The defer attribute tells the browser not to wait for the script. Instead, the browser will continue to process the HTML, build DOM.

Just remove that attribute for socket.io script tag and keep it as it is for another js tag.
Like this :

Make sure you get js code loaded when you get `http://localhost:3008/socket.io/socket.io.js` in the browser.

Hope this helps!! Please comment if you get any issues or doubts later.